# How do I set an error message on binding source filter if item etc doesnt exist

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a filter so it filters the binding source by the customerID. But what if the customer id doesnt exist? When i enter id = 3 and doesnt exist it messes up my whole binding per say, meaning it nulls everything and when i want to reopen the binding it crashes saying it cant locate the item. So trying not to go into detail with the errors, i want to make it so if it results back to null then present the user with an error saying not located etc and enter again, if correct/present then do its filter job.

My code:

```
dim filterstring as string
    filterstring = CStr(bsorder.Filter = "id = " & custid & "")
                If filterstring.Count() = 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Error! try again!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Else

                        bsorder.Filter = "ID = " & custid & ""

                End If
```

Comment: Care to explain further? - give examples or such please? I was actually just reading a brief post on here about the whole option strict and option explicit but first time coming a cross this whole procedure :z I was fixing my code and testing it all out to make it to perfection until i came across that little bug with if it doesnt exist it doesnt give an error etc :L

Comment: Isnt it something like Option strict on? I put that in my code then before the code end do Option strict off?

Comment: Is option strict a good thing to have on? And with that said, will it upset any my other code?:o

Comment: It revealed like 30 haha xD Thanks for the surprise mentor ;) Its giving me these auto fixes so im testing the autofixes to make sure they are correct - aka my program works with them. With that said, since this is activated (do i dim strfilter as string then or?) and how would i go about counting this to see if its null in the filter?

Comment: To be honest, i tried using: if bs.filter is nothing then statement and few others but same result.. As for what you are saying above i dont understand what you mean :/
Heres my updated code: http://pastebin.com/ETQuXfM1

Comment: Ok i am understanding a bit:)
But i did this: http://pastebin.com/SyJ8APgV
And still didnt work:/ it just nulls my fields and i cant reopen the bindingsource.

Comment: When i search for id: 3 and it doesnt exist it blanks my stuff as in the photo i am about to show and then when i reopen the search for order (to reset it and go back to normal state without filter) i get the error which is on the same link. http://imgur.com/a/xkORA

Comment: When you press the tab to search for order in that code i have: `bsorder.Filter = ""
call UpdateBindingsOrder()
        bsorder.DataSource = dtorder` so everytime that runs and clears filters etc. As for the try/catch, i still dont understand. I put whats in the pastebin (Thats my understanding on using it) XD

Like this: http://pastebin.com/LEvTezmz ?

Comment: Im no pro with filters and how to check if a filter is nulled etc, your the one to show me what a filter is with binding sources, heck.. your the one who introduced me to this whole bindingsource thing xD Im a pretty basic guy that knows the basic to coding in vb, when i see something i reuse recreate it and enhances my knowledge but terms your using to try make me understand fully is not connecting with me, i honestly dont know what i am doing with this try/catch thing:/

Comment: @Plutonix i tried and dont know, is there just a simple thing to go yeah there is no id = custid or whatever i inputed so cant continue else if the id is there go ahead and filter it to the id.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this? If do just post the answer please. I dont know what i am doing, my attempt is above and aint working. From the answer i can study and reuse in the future. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my code, thought the above would work but doesnt.

Comment: Sounds good plutonix, i thought i demonstrated my notion above when i did use the whole try/catch but didnt work xD As for blaming you? No way man, im not blaming you for nothing!:O If it wasnt for you, i wouldnt be as far as i am now :( I appreciate every single bit of the help you gave me! Really do appreciate it:) You gave me more teaching than my tutor thats for sure! I did throw some helpful tips out of the window true, but its due to the fact the code doesnt need to be the best. Once working, i get distinction xD Got other projects in VB to be working on :/

Comment: I watched videos on this try / catch. From what i learned is the catch catches errors and with them you can make it display a error message with messagebox's? I came up with this: `Try
                    bsorder.Filter = "CustomerID = " & custid & ""
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("error", ex.ToString)
                End Try`
But my messagebox didnt show? See its not given me an error, its just nulling my textboxes and such? Like the pics i showed in imgur?

Comment: @Plutonix I dont no how to get into the catch section? Its not catching anything for me.. Just running the try part :/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BWNyUNc5 is the formload and updatebindingsorder etc. Basically i am using the thing you told me to do. So whenever i select to search for a order or customer it opens a new bindingsource using: `Call UpdateBindingsOrder()
                bsorder.DataSource = dtorder` This starts everything fresh for me so it works for my scenario :)

Comment: Basically, If i enter 1 or 2 it filters perfectly as they exist if you get me? But if i enter a customerid that does not exist in that table (Example, customerid 1 and 2 is present but nothing else) i want it to go: No customer found please enter another id. But what happens is what i showed in them screenshots in imgur. When i enter lets say 6 (doesnt exist) it blanks all my textbox's as if it filtered to 6 but it doesnt exist so its blanking them? Then if i enter id 2 it gives me an error: DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings. I dont get it D:

Comment: Well if you disgard everything i said then. But know this, i want to make it so if customerid doesnt exist in database if i try filter it to id 5 (doesnt exist) I dont want it to filter as it doesnt exist but instead i want it to display a messagebox. But if it does exist i want it to work. How do i achieve this? I have it so if u enter and it exists it works but i dont have a solution to how to stop it and display a message if it doesnt exist (This is my aim XD)

Comment: Let me explain quickly. I have it so when you press the search order tab in the menubar it calls the method : searchorder. Within that method it has all the buttons.visible etc etc but also has: `Call UpdateBindingsOrder()
        bsorder.DataSource = dtorder
        bsorder.MoveFirst()
        BtnPrev.Enabled = (bsorder.Position > 0)
        BtnStart.Enabled = (bsorder.Position > 0)`
I have this so it resets my changes made and makes it default back to a new search and put its back to first item (bs.movefirst) <- dont mind this, its my own design nothing to do with filters.

Comment: But then when you open the searchorder section a new tab appears (Filters which has a side menu called "By customers") Within that i have the following code: http://pastebin.com/EeuWahZD
All i want it to do is filter the search of the order BY whatever customerID you enter. If it exists it will filter the order by that customer id, if it doesnt exist i just want it to simply display an error and do nothing else. Thats all i want it to do, do you understand what i am trying to do? If so, is it possible? Sorry if im explaining badly :/

Comment: But with that said, back to the searchorder method. I have that updatebindings etc to reset my searchorder back to default. It only enables buttons and stuff within that method. But using updatebindings and such puts my bindingsource back to the original state in which i want it do be. If i press my button(Search by id) It shows that 1 order by its ID but what if i left it like that? It would be stuck so with the reset method i came up with, it puts it back to default state:)  My filter code is separate and is in the filters section which i explain right above this reply ^

Comment: Simply put and for the last time, there is no need to requery the DB (`UpdateBindingsOrder`) or reset the DataSource (`bsorder.DataSource = dtorder`) in order to search, find or filter.  It is not a coincidence that you get the exception on that line of code.  I'd help if I could but you went off the reservation long ago with your one-form-does-all approach.

Comment: The reason i am doing this is cause when i search for id 2 it displays id 2 and the id 1 disappears thats why i have that line. But none of that matters as it works and does what i need it to do. I only need help with this whole filter by customerid. It works, only thing is.. IF i enter an id that doesnt exist it nulls everything and messes things up. I just need something to stop the filter if it doesnt exist and display a message, if it exists itl filter by that customer id. Sadly, i cant get it to stop if it doesnt exist. Im asking please, can you help me with this last thing?:/

Comment: This seems to be the last issue with my program. The program works, i can search, delete, add and filter customers and the same for orders only thing is.. The filter part with orders works but when you enter the id that dont exist it doesnt stop and give an error messagebox like i want it to do. Its probs something so small that im missing out on or something? I could hook it to a combo box like you said before? Load the ids into the combo box some how (all the available ids) Then itl prevent me in fixing this with the input method. Then all i need to do is select id and press filter - done:)

Comment: Do you think using the input method is good or what way would you go about making a filter by customer for orders? The input one im using is quick, enter the customer id and it works but only issue is if it doesnt exist it trys to filter anyway..

Comment: You are using the filter to find IDs, thats fine.  But if you search for #2, #1 is **supposed to disappear** because #1 <> #2.  If you want to remove the filter, you **dont** have to requery the database and reset the bindingsource's datasource.  Just remove the filter.

Comment: I do just remove the filter? Your confusing me now haha. I think i might of explained it totally wrong, when the filter is set i have it so my "Remove filter" Button appears and once clicked the code is: bsorder.filter = "" which you told me? And that works? The requery of the database and reset is for another thing i done (Please do not worry about that thats grand it works, no need to think about that) I have `bsorder.filter = ""` in my open searchother also to remove filters to reset the search.

Comment: In plain terms (I am truly sorry for all this confusion i made) I only need a solution in making it so if i enter an id that does not exist that it doesnt continue filtering, it displays my messagebox and stops the query. If it does exist, it will filter like normal using: `bsorder.Filter = "CustomerID = " & custid & ""`

Comment: @Plutonix so would you have a solution to prevent the filter happening if the entered id doesnt exist?

Comment: Its not crashing on bsorder, it only crashes on that line when i reopen search order to reset itself. But i dont care bout that, it wont even crash if i have the solution in making it so it doesnt filter if i enter a id that doesnt exist. If i enter a id that DOES EXIST and click search order tab i get no errors cause it clears perfectly?  When i enter id 2 (Customer exists) I get: http://imgur.com/UTA4l2v
When i enter id 3 (Doesnt exist) i get: http://imgur.com/u6V2eOL
Here i want it to display my messagebox. (if doesnt exist display messagebox and dont continue)

Comment: When i then enter id 1 or 2 again since id 3 didnt work i get an error: http://imgur.com/XHk6idV
Hopefully you can understand @plutonix

Comment: Im getting this error in my knowledge BECAUSE it is filtering the table TO ID 3 that DOESNT exist you get me? Cause it doesnt exist its filtering to it and given back a null reference / result per say so it blanks my box's but when i enter another id to filter to only that id i get that error which is showed in the screen above this reply ^.

Comment: I just want a simple scenario so when i enter id 3 (doesnt exist) it will throw me my messagebox and stop the code! But if i enter id 2 or 1 or whatever id that DOES exist then it will continue on working with `bsorder.Filter = "CustomerID = " & custid & ""` thats all i want. I only need that then no error will occur elsewere. Do you have a solution to prevent the filter from working if the id doesnt exist? As id 3 is non existent it shouldnt continue and null my stuff, i want it to stop and if it does exist then bam.. work away filtering!:)

Comment: I have `bsorder.Filter = "CustomerID = " & custid & ""
                    If bsorder.Count = 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("no id found")
                    End If`
And if i enter id thats there it filters but when i enter an id like 3 that doesnt the messagebox works but still filters as if id 3 exists (But nulls everything like discussed above) So is there a way to use this .counts result to stop the filter commences if doesnt exist etc? Thanks @Plutonix :)

Comment: While waiting on you, i tested the try method more and more and well.. I succeeded in completing my project! Technically i succeeded but now i just need to add an email feature in which i have no clue, il wait on my tutor to tell me that haha. Thanks a million @plutonix ! You been a great help and for not giving up on me:D Cheers pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to check if the row existed before applying the filter, to do so i used a Try/Catch method to successfully know rather the id existed or not. The code that worked is below:

```
Try
                Using myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.\yous.accdb")
                    myConnection.Open()
                    Dim str As String
                    str = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE whateverID=@ID "
                    Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", custid)
                        Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                            If dr.HasRows Then
                                dr.Read()

                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```